# create new session in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to see how rows blocking work in oracle(SQL*Plus). So I want two sessions or users interact with one table, and to see locks. How to create these sessions or users? I guess that the question is quite stupid, but I can't understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well a bit broad but

If you create a table, put a record in it.
Then in your tool to run a query do something like

```
Begin Transaction
Update myTytable set MyColumn = 'Fred' Where MyKey = 1
```

Now you have an update transaction with at least that row locked.

The open up another connection and do

```
Update myTytable set MyColumn = 'Bill' Where MyKey = 1
```

That row is locked so this query will be blocked until it is timed out, or you go back to the first query, and do a commit or rollback transaction.

There's a lot more to locking, and it can be very specific to a dbms, but this should give you a start on forcing a lock, so you can investigate.

Answer (score 0):

Open two terminals and from each of them connect with SQL*Plus: this will open two sessions. (Single user is enough).